# ¿Cómo implementar una imagen en un :hover?

Tags: html5, css3

Mi pregunta es; ¿como a la hora de activar el hover de un "LI" agregar una imagen al costado? En este caso un Check de verificación. 
Sería una simple imagen agregada al cambio de color que ya tiene implementado.

HTML:

```
<article>
        <div id="Menulateral">
           <h1>Frutas</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Citricos</li>
                <li>Platano y Banana</li>
                <li>Manzanas</li>
                <li>Peras</li>
                <li>Melocotón</li>
                <li>Melón</li>
                <li>Sandía</li>
                <li>Uvas</li>
                <li>Frutos del bosque</li>
                <li>Fruta tropical</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

     </article>
```

CSS:

```
#Menulateral li:hover{
color: greenyellow;
```

Gracias. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo. Lo que hay que hacer es agregar una imagen luego de cada texto, dentro de cada `<li>`. Inicialmente va a tener una propiedad "display:none" para ocultarlo y luego al hacer hover sobre cada li vamos a cambiar dicha propiead a "display:inline-block". El resto ya son ajustes para alinear mas a la derecha o izquierda. Saludos!

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}

li .ico {
  position: absolute;
  float: rigth;
  display: none;
}

li:hover .ico {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menulateral">
  <h1>Frutas</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Citricos
      <img class="ico" src="https://www.infobae.com/new-resizer/2eXm-aeu7yy_tdJIi9UTBOuT7qs=/750x0/filters:quality(100)/s3.amazonaws.com/arc-wordpress-client-uploads/infobae-wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/04092504/citricos_1.jpg" width="150" />
    </li>
    <li>Platano y Banana
    <img class="ico" src="https://mejorconsalud.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/banana-4.jpg" width="150" />
    </li>
    <li>Manzanas
    <img class="ico" src="http://www.redagricola.com/cl/assets/uploads/2017/08/xmanazana-792x591-c-default.jpg.pagespeed.ic.X_s5-6luAc.jpg" width="150" />
    </li>
    <li>Peras
    <img class="ico" src="http://www.cajanature.com/405-large_default/pera-ecologica-.jpg" width="150" />
    </li>
    <li>Melocotón
    <img class="ico" src="http://www.5septiembre.cu/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Foto-melocot%C3%B3n-1-copia-listo.jpg" width="16" />
    </li>
    <li>Melón
    <img class="ico" src="https://i.blogs.es/b32837/melon/450_1000.jpg" width="150" />
    </li>
    <li>Sandía
    <img class="ico" src="https://hortamar.es/wp-content/uploads/sandia-hortamar-1.jpg" width="150" />
    </li>
    <li>Uvas
    <img class="ico" src="https://cdnmundo1.img.sputniknews.com/images/107176/13/1071761388.jpg" width="150" />
    </li>
    <li>Frutos del bosque
    <img class="ico" src="img/ico/arrow_f.png" width="150" />
    </li>
    <li>Fruta tropical
    <img class="ico" src="img/ico/arrow_f.png" width="150" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Magnífico Fran, era lo que necesitaba. Muchas Gracias